# Change working directory for Maven failsafe pre-integration-test to find Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-failsafe-plugin

We have a multi module Maven project with multiple executable projects inside.

The directory structure looks similar to this:

```
parent
+- module1
+-- src/main/resources/application.yml
+-- config/bootstrap.yml
+-- config/application-dev.yml
+-- config/application-prod.yml
+-- pom.xml
+- pom.xml
```

where `application.yml` are packaged default values that are not environment specific and all files in the `config` folder belongs to external configuration needed only for local development which is not part of the WAR file.

Now if I start the application or tests from the IDE it works as expected. Also, if I run Maven builds in `module1` folder. However, if I try to build the parent project, the `bootstrap.yml` is not found which fails the build during the `pre-integration-test` phase.

I discovered that the working directory is set to the parent folder instead of `module1` which seems to be the problem as Spring looks in `.` and `./config`. If I duplicate the config folder to root, it works in all cases.

Is there any way to tell Maven failsafe to set the working directory to the module folder during `pre-integration-test` phase where the Spring Context looks for the configuration?

`parent/pom.xml`:

```
<project ...>
    <properties>
        <maven.version>3.0.0</maven.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.18.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.20.1</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-failsafe-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

`parent/module1/pom.xml`:

```
<project>
    <parent>
        ...
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please show your pom files it sounds like you are doing something wrong...

Comment: POM files are rather huge, I hope I added the relevant excerpts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for some reason both `<environmentVariables>` and `<systemProperties>` in the `<config>` block of `maven-failsafe-plugin` does not work in combination with `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

It appears that spring-boot plugin is responsible to create the (forked) JVM in the `pre-integration-test` phase because of this snippet:

```
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
```

I solved it by configuring the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` instead:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
```

According to documentation `${basedir}` should be the default but maybe it doesn't work with Maven multi-module projects.